# Can I use linear regression when one group has positive correlation and another negative of X with Y?

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction

I am wondering if I can use regression of the type Y=a+b1*X1*D1+b2*X2*D1+b3*X3*D1+...
As a result, I am planning to use dummy group variable for each of X's.
The assumption of the linear regression tells that should present: Multivariate normality. from the plot I can see if ignore groups, there does not exist normal distribution in Xs.
Does my regression make sense? Or is it better to use some quadratic functions of the variables? If not, which one should I use in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your plots, the slopes differs among the groups. So introduce group dummy variables. If you have a model of the form
$$ Y_i= a + b_1 x_{i1} + b_2 x_{i2} + \cdots + c_1 D_{i1} + \cdots $$
Then you just gets different *intercepts* between the groups, but the groups all have the same slopes. To get different slopes, you need *interactions*, as in
$$ Y_i = \text{above} + g_1 x_{i1} D_{i1} + \cdots
$$
With R formula notation, this can be expressed succinctly as

```r
    formula= x + D
```

which is the equal slopes case, versus with interactions

```r
    formula= x*D
```

which has the eqivalent, expanded form

```r
    formula= x + D + x:D
```